# Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring Security to my existing Spring project. After putting the code below to my pom.xml, i got the error "Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE" in my eclipse. What is the problem? Thanks!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Spring security doesn't have a 3.2.5 release yet. Don't use the `${spring-framework.version}` for Spring Security.

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core

Comment: As M. Deinum mentioned, Spring Security is a different project than Spring Framework with its own lifecycle (just like Spring WebFlow, Spring Batch, ...).